# xcode 4 have library resources automatically appear in the main project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, resources

I have a static library.  Let's call it MyLibrary.  I am using it in 5 different Xcode projects.  It has a lot of resource files.  New resources are added reasonably often.  And changes to existing resources are common.  Obviously, I want to set things up so that changes to the library resources are reflected in all 5 projects, without my having to update the other projects.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is to create a resource bundle / bundles for your static library. In your dependent projects, point to the bundle from the library (including a bundle entails a single reference in the project file). 
It is easy to update resources from your bundle - simply add / change / remove the resource files from the physical location of the bundle (on disk). Your dependent projects will automatically reflect these changes.